# Copy assembly dependencies from lib folder that uses SVN

Tags: c#, .net, svn, msbuild, assemblies

I have been investigating the best way to store our solutions in SVN and came up with a structure of:

> - Libraries
>
>   - EntLib
>   - DLLs
>   - Global
>
>     - DLLs
>   - SubSonic
>
>     - DLLs
> - Source
>
>   - sln
>   - Project 1
>   - Project 2

Libraries uses svn:externals to pull down the correct version of the assemblies.

My issue is that "Global" has dependencies on other assemblies.  These are included in the Global folder.  My question is what is the best process for copying these dependency DLLs to the output folder if they aren't referenced by the projects that use "Global"?

I have tried just referencing the files and setting `CopyLocal` to `True` but the dependencies are not being found when running the code.

This then lead me to using MSBuild to copy all of the DLLs in "Libraries" to the projects "output" folder using the Copy task which has the attribute `SkipUnchangedFiles`, but this relies on file size and timestamp to decide whether the file is newer.  This will not work if there is a different version of the file with the same size and older.  I don't want to copy all of the files every time a build runs unless I **absolutely** have to.

Any help/past experiences would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies...`SkipUnchangedFiles` checks that the timestamps are different not that they are newer so this will work in our scenario.